# How to speed up webpack Uglify

Tags: webpack

Is there any way to speed up webpack uglify step?

I tried setting sourceMaps property to false and that helps.

```
   uglifyPlugin = new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    }),
```